# The fixed points of two computable functions

Tags: recursion, computability, fixed-points

I am trying to solve a question in Computabiltiy Theory which says:

> Let $f, g$ be two computable functions. Prove that there exist numbers
> $e_1, e_2$ such that:
>
> $ \phi_{f(e_1)} = \phi_{e_2}$
>
> $ \phi_{g(e_2)} = \phi_{e_1}$

Where $\phi_n$ denotes the program with the corresponding code $n$.

My original idea was to use the Recursion Theorem and construct a computable function that's able to work with the fixed points of the two functions $f,g$ and construct the $e_1, e_2$ that way. But that seems to not work and I am not sure if I'm on the right path or not.

I would appreciate any hints or ideas on the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what $\phi$ is

Comment: @StiftungWarentest I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe looking at compositions $fg$ and $gf$ might be useful.

Comment: @tses My problem is that $\phi_{f(e_1)}=\phi_{e_1}$ does not imply that $f(e_1) = e_2$.

Comment: @Sajad What about the other way around? If you define $e_2 := f(e_1)$ (for a suitable choice of $e_1$)?

Comment: @tses Well then it's trivial! I did not thank of that at all. Thanks.